# Integer ID vs Character ID in redux

Tags: redux, state

I need to be able to reference items by username and slug. I currently have my state shape like this:

```
posts: {
    user1_postslug: {...},
    user2_postslug1: {...},
}
```

But I'm worried that this will eventually affect performance, so I thought about doing it like this instead:

```
posts: {
    items: {
        4: {...},
        21: {...},
    },
    references: {
        user1_postslug: 21,
        user2_postslug1: 4,
    }
}
```

Here I am storing them by their numbered id, and storing references to them. Is there any reason I shouldn't be using the above code, or the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example is probably closer to what you want, although you may want to tweak it a bit further.  The new [Structuring Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) section in the Redux docs has a page on [Normalizing State Shape](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html), which should be relevant.

Don't see any actual concerns with performance here, though.